# Oracle materialized view log

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

If I have `table T` with 10 columns and create materialized view log with only 3 of them as well as materialized view with those 3, why when I updated ANY column in the table (besides those in the log) the record is inserted into `MLOG$_T` ? Is there a way to avoid?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't avoid it. The primary purpose of the log is to identify the rows that have changed, not the changed data itself (although you can include that in the log as well). The process for maintaining the log doesn't know anything about the view(s) that might be created that will use the logs, so it has to maintain the log for any change in the table.

This of it this way: suppose you later create another materialized view on the same table that uses other columns. If the log is to be useful, it must maintain information about changes for those rows as well. After all, you can only create one log per table.